# Failed WriteBatch Operation with py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I am trying to find a workaround to the following problem.  I have seen it quasi-described in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023072/py2neo-using-get-or-create-in-writebatch), yet not really answered.

The following code fails, starting with a fresh graph:

```
from py2neo import neo4j

def add_test_nodes():
    # Add a test node manually
    alice = g.get_or_create_indexed_node("Users", "user_id", 12345, {"user_id":12345})

def do_batch(graph):
    # Begin batch write transaction
    batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph)

    # get some updated node properties to add
    new_node_data = {"user_id":12345, "name": "Alice"}

    # batch requests
    a = batch.get_or_create_in_index(neo4j.Node, "Users", "user_id", 12345, {})
    batch.set_properties(a, new_node_data)  #<-- I'm the problem

    # execute batch requests and clear
    batch.run()
    batch.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initialize Graph DB service and create a Users node index
    g = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()
    users_idx = g.get_or_create_index(neo4j.Node, "Users")

    # run the test functions
    add_test_nodes()
    alice = g.get_or_create_indexed_node("Users", "user_id", 12345)
    print alice

    do_batch(g)

    # get alice back and assert additional properties were added
    alice = g.get_or_create_indexed_node("Users", "user_id", 12345)
    assert "name" in alice
```

In short, I wish, in one batch transaction, to update existing indexed node properties.  The failure is occurring at the `batch.set_properties` line, and it is because the `BatchRequest` object returned by the previous line is not being interpreted as a valid node.  Though not entirely indentical, it feels like I am attempting something like the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19864596/1513010)

Some specifics

```
>>> import py2neo
>>> py2neo.__version__
'1.6.0'
>>> g = py2neo.neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()
>>> g.neo4j_version
(2, 0, 0, u'M06')
```

### Update

If I split the problem into separate batches, then it can run without error:

```
def do_batch(graph):
    # Begin batch write transaction
    batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph)

    # get some updated node properties to add
    new_node_data = {"user_id":12345, "name": "Alice"}

    # batch request 1
    batch.get_or_create_in_index(neo4j.Node, "Users", "user_id", 12345, {})

    # execute batch request and clear
    alice = batch.submit()
    batch.clear()

    # batch request 2
    batch.set_properties(a, new_node_data)

    # execute batch request and clear
    batch.run()
    batch.clear()
```

This works for many nodes as well.  Though I do not love the idea of splitting the batch up, this might be the only way at the moment.  Anyone have some comments on this?

Comment: submitted [Issue #221 to py2neo](https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo/issues/221)

Comment: Thanks for submitting the issue.  The response steered me to the solution that I was looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading up on all the new features of Neo4j 2.0.0-M06, it seems that the older workflow of node and relationship indexes are being superseded.  There is presently a bit of a divergence on the part of neo in the way indexing is done.  Namely, [labels](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/graphdb-neo4j-labels.html) and [schema indexes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/graphdb-neo4j-schema.html).

### Labels

Labels can be arbitrarily attached to nodes and can serve as a reference for an index.

### Indexes

Indexes can be created in Cypher by referencing Labels (here, `User`) and node property key, (`screen_name`):

```
CREATE INDEX ON :User(screen_name)
```

### Cypher `MERGE`

Furthermore, the indexed `get_or_create` methods are now possible via the new cypher [`MERGE`](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-merge.html) function, which incorporate Labels and their indexes quite succinctly:

```
MERGE (me:User{screen_name:"SunPowered"}) RETURN me
```

### Batch

Queries of the sort can be batched in `py2neo` by appending a CypherQuery instance to the batch object:

```
from py2neo import neo4j

graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()
cypher_merge_user = neo4j.CypherQuery(graph_db, 
    "MERGE (user:User {screen_name:{name}}) RETURN user")

def get_or_create_user(screen_name):
    """Return the user if exists, create one if not"""
    return cypher_merge_user.execute_one(name=screen_name)

def get_or_create_users(screen_names):
    """Apply the get or create user cypher query to many usernames in a 
    batch transaction"""
    
    batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph_db)
    
    for screen_name in screen_names:
        batch.append_cypher(cypher_merge_user, params=dict(name=screen_name))

    return batch.submit()

root = get_or_create_user("Root")
users = get_or_create_users(["alice", "bob", "charlie"])
```

### Limitation

There is a limitation, however, in that the results from a cypher query in a batch transaction cannot be referenced later in the same transaction.  The original question was in reference to updating a collection of indexed user properties in one batch transaction.  This is still not possible, as far as I can muster.  For example, the following snippet throws an error:

```
batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph_db)
b1 = batch.append_cypher(cypher_merge_user, params=dict(name="Alice"))
batch.set_properties(b1, dict(last_name="Smith")})
resp = batch.submit()
```

So, it seems that although there is a bit less overhead in implementing the `get_or_create` over a labelled node using `py2neo` because the legacy indexes are no longer necessary, the original question still needs 2 separate batch transactions to complete.

Comment: For applying labels to indexed nodes (which also has this same error), I ended up just creating my nodes with a `__label` property and then running a Cypher query after to fix the labels: `MATCH (n {__label:"Worker"}) WITH n SET n:Worker REMOVE n.__label;`. +1 for the detailed answer. I was having the exact same problem at the exact same time. Nice to see someone else's solution!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems not to be in `batch.set_properties()` but rather in the output of `batch.get_or_create_in_index()`. If you add the node with `batch.create()`, it works:

```
db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()

batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(db)
# create a node instead of getting it from index
test_node = batch.create({'key': 'value'})
# set new properties on the node
batch.set_properties(test_node, {'key': 'foo'})

batch.submit()
```

If you have a look at the properties of the BatchRequest object returned by `batch.create()` and `batch.get_or_create_in_index()` there is a difference in the URI because the methods use different parts of the neo4j REST API:

```
test_node = batch.create({'key': 'value'})
print test_node.uri # node
print test_node.body # {'key': 'value'}
print test_node.method # POST

index_node = batch.get_or_create_in_index(neo4j.Node, "Users", "user_id", 12345, {})
print index_node.uri # index/node/Users?uniqueness=get_or_create
print index_node.body # {u'value': 12345, u'key': 'user_id', u'properties': {}}
print index_node.method # POST

batch.submit()
```

So I guess `batch.set_properties()` somehow can't handle the URI of the indexed node? I.e. it doesn't really get the correct URI for the node?

Doesn't solve the problem, but could be a pointer for somebody else ;) ?

Comment: Yes, this is true.  Thanks.  My issue with this, is that I wish to have the nodes be unique, and they may already exist, thus the call to `get_or_create_in_index()`  I was hoping it would return either the existing node or create a new one and return the instance to that.

Comment: That's exactly what the `get_or_create_in_index()` is made for. I think it should work and we could call this a bug. I bet a certain Nigel Small will be able to shed some light on this ;) Till then it might make sense to check the neo4j rest api docs for clues?